# Unable to pass a native value in ActionLink under Razor while POCO instances work great

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

First I thought that I'm using the wrong overload again (a very common gotcha in the API - everybody trips over that one). But wouldn't you know? That's not it. I actually had the HTML attributes parameter too and I verified with intellisense that it's the route values I'm entering.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Poof", "Action", "Home", 10, new { @class = "nav-link" })
```

Nevertheless, it seem that the receiving method below only sees *null* and crashes as it can't make an integer out of it.

```
public ActionResult Record(int count) { ... }
```

I've tried a few things: changed parameter type to *int?* and *string* (the program  stops crashing but the value is still null). I've tested to package the passed value as an object (with/without @).

```
@Html.ActionLink("Poof", "Record", "Home", 
  new { count = "bamse" }, 
  new { @class = "nav-link" })
```

I can see that the anchor produced has my value as a query string, so the changes are there. However, I still get *null* only in the method.

What am I missing?

The weird thing is that the following works fine.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Poof", "Record", "Home", 
  new Thing(), 
  new { @class = "nav-link" })

public ActionResult Record(Thing count) { ... }
```

Comment: and how is your routing configured?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Not sure what you're asking about. If you refer to the routing pattern file, it's untouched. I'm using the very defaulty  one fro the template.

Comment: check RouteConfig.cs in your solution what written inside that

Comment: As I said, it's the default one with no changes. Also, when I try to pass an object from my POCO classes, it works. It seems to fail on native types...

Comment: To answer yor question:       routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );

Comment: That's because `int` does not have any properties. Note if you quoted it (i.e. `"10"`) you would get `?length=2`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I though so too. The I tested to pass the bagger wrapped in an object like this: *new {count=10}*. Still the same issue, though. How should I pass a simple integer value?!

Comment: Using `new { count = 10 }` will work fine (did you omit the `new`)? I'll add an answer shortly explaining how it works internally

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nope, I haven't... Just rechecked it. And given the surprised attitude from the community, I'm prone to believe that the best course of action is to try a brand new project and recreate the issue there, as to exclude the possibility of something weird being hidden in mine. Post your answer, please and by then, I'll have more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) of `@Html.ActionLink()` that expects the 4th parameter to be typeof `object`. Internally the method builds a `RouteValueDictionary` by using the `.ToString()` value of each property in the object.

In your case your 'object' (an `int`) has no properties, so no route values are generated and the url will be just `/Home/Action`(and you program crashes because your method expects a non null parameter).

If for example you changed it to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Poof", "Action", "Home", "10", new { @class = "nav-link" })
```

i.e. quoting the 4th parameter, the url would now be `/Home/Action?length=2` because typeof `string` has a property `length` and there a 2 characters in the value.

In order to pass a native value you need to use the format

```
@Html.ActionLink("Poof", "Action", "Home", new { count = 10 }, new { @class = "nav-link" })
```

Which will generate `/Home/Action?count=10` (or `/Home/Action/10` if you create a specific route definition with `Home/Action/{count}`)

Note also that passing a POCO in your case only works correctly because your POCO contains only value type properties. If for example, it also contained a property which was (say) `public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }` then the url created would include `?Numbers=System.Collections.Generic.List[int]` (and binding would fail) so be careful passing complex objects in an action link

Comment: This was one kick-butt explanation. I see where I tripped (plus, the browser kind of cached some stuff leading to a full confusion). As for you last remark (+1 for that, by the way), how would one send over somplex object that have properties consisting of lists? Is it a no-no?

Comment: Definitely a no-no. In order to bind, the query string would need to be something like `...?Numbers[0]=15&Numbers[1]=43&Numbers[2]=57` etc which (apart from being a really ugly query string) could easily exceed the query string limit and throw and exception (which is why I assume the MVC team did not use a recursive method to generate the route values on collections or nested complex properties)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what might be wrong with your code from the information provided in your question but assuming **total defaults** (a newly created ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio), if you add the following markup in your `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`:

```
Html.ActionLink(
    "Poof", 
    "Record", 
    "Home",
    new { count = "bamse" },
    new { @class = "nav-link" }
)
```

and the following action in your `HomeController`:

```
public ActionResult Record(string count)
{
    return Content(count);
}
```

upon clicking on the generated anchor, the correct action will be invoked and the correct parameter passed to it.

The generated markup will look like this:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Record?count=bamse">Poof</a>
```

So I guess that now the question that you should be asking yourself is: how does my setup differs with what Darin has outlined here? Answering this question might hold the key to your problem.

---

UPDATE:

OK, now you seem to have changed your question. You seem to be trying to pass complex objects to your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Record(Thing count) { ... }
```

Of course this doesn't work as you might expect. So make sure that you pass every single property that you want to be available when constructing your anchor:

```
Html.ActionLink(
    "Poof", 
    "Record", 
    "Home",
    new { ThingProp1 = "prop1", ThingProp2 = "prop2" },
    new { @class = "nav-link" }
)
```

Alternatively, and of course a much better approach to handle this situation is to attribute an unique identifier to your models, so that all its needed in order to retrieve this model from your backend is this identifier:

```
Html.ActionLink(
    "Poof", 
    "Record", 
    "Home",
    new { id = "123" },
    new { @class = "nav-link" }
)
```

and then in your controller action simply use this identifier to retrieve your `Thing`:

```
public ActionResult Record(int id) 
{
    Thing model = ... fetch the Thing using its identifier
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed to paste in the whole question. Please see the last part of the code working with POCO instances but not with natives. I changed the question while typing and pasted in wrong version. My bad.

Comment: OK, now I see your updated question. You seem to be attempting to pass some complex object to the action. In this case you will need to specify every single property in your 4th argument of the `ActionLink`. Please see my updated answer for an example. You cannot just pass an object there. You should use an anonymous object in which you set every single scalar property of your `Thing` model. But of course a much better approach is to simply pass an identifier of this object that would allow you to retrieve it on the server.

Comment: Also you might consider changing the title of your question. It's exactly the contrary to your scenario. Native values (integers, strings, ...) work great, while POCO objects do not.

Comment: I see I wasn't clear. Actually the title is spot-on. When I'm trying to pass a *new Vehicle()* or *new Record()*, that actual works as supposed to. Now, I'm doing a new call and I only need to pass an int (int's not related to the complex types at all, I just meant to show that it's not the routing, as one might first suspect. So it's actually the native types (int, string etc.) that get null value in the parameter (I'm changing the parameter type for each call, of course).

Comment: Hmm, an `int` can never be `null`. This simply doesn't make any sense. It violates the most basic rules of what a value types are in the CLR. An `int` is a value type, so the closest it could be is `0`, but not `null`. Probably that's why I must have misunderstood your question. Anyway, as seen in my initial answer, creating a new ASP.NET MVC application, placing an anchor in the default view as shown in my answer and a corresponding controller action with a `string` signature works as expected. So I really don't see what the actual problem with your code might be.

Comment: When I had *int* the program crashed (because it was trying to fit the *null* value into an integer). Then I tested with *int?* and also *string*. They got null (no crash of course). I'll try to reproduce the problem with a brand new, vanilla project. You're right about that.

Comment: Did you try creating a new ASP.NET MVC project? Then did you try placing an anchor in your `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` view with the following contents `Html.ActionLink("Poof", "Record", "Home", new { count = "bamse" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })`? And finally adding the corresponding action in your `HomeController` as shown in my answer: `public ActionResult Record(string count) { ... }`? Did this work for you? You really should try to narrow down the problem.